# Example of $f(x) +f(2x) \neq 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, examples-counterexamples

Given $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)+f(2x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ not exist.

Does it imply that $f(x) +f(2x)=0$ and only that?

Can't find examples for the sum not equal to zero.

Thank you.

Comment: If $f$ is a function such that $f(x)+f(2x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to0} f(x)$ does not exist, then $g(x)=f(x)+x$ satisfies the two conditions in the first line but $g(x)+g(2x)\ne0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try $$f(x) = x + \sin(\pi \log_2(|x|))$$

Comment: Can you elaborate how the sum isn't zero?

Comment: $\sin(\pi \log_2(|x|)) + \sin(\pi \log_2(|2x|)) = 0$ but $x + 2x \ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

(Edited)
Here is an example: $f(x) = x + \sin(\pi \log_2 |x|), $ for $x\neq 0$ and set $f(0)=1$. You can easily show that $f(x)+f(2x)\neq 0$ holds for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. However, $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)+f(2x) = 0,$ while $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: Can u elaborate?

Comment: Yes, I did that just now. Note, $|x|$ is there just to make $f(x)$ well-defined for $x<0$ as well.

Comment: That's not what I asked. I asked if the sum can be not zero.

Comment: Okay then just add $x$ to my $f(x).$ I noticed that Robert Israel did exactly this.

Comment: Well, while you are considering limit as $x\to 0,$ the value of $f(0)$ does not matter. So you can just separately define $f(0) = 1,$ say. Then $f(x)+f(2x) = 3x\neq 0$ when $x\neq 0,$ and $f(0)+f(2\cdot 0) = 2\neq 0.$

Comment: Thanks you I'll try to understand your steps.